# Meteorite fails at cloning from git repo

Tags: git, meteor, meteorite

I've just installed meteorite on two of my Manjaro PCs and both gives the same error when trying to add packages. I've tried to reinstall meteorite, run with sudo, check that git is installed but none of it worked.

This is what happens:

```
$ mrt add iron-router
✓ iron-router
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.7.1
child process timed out, no activity for 15 seconds 

ERROR: null Command failed: Cloning into '/home/myuser/.meteorite/source/EventedMind/iron-router'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 3288, done.        
remote: Total 3288 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)         KiB/s   
Receiving objects: 100% (3288/3288), 841.35 KiB | 335.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1871/1871), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Unexpected end of command stream


STDOUT:  

STDERR: Cloning into '/home/myuser/.meteorite/source/EventedMind/iron-router'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 3288, done.        
remote: Total 3288 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)         KiB/s   
Receiving objects: 100% (3288/3288), 841.35 KiB | 335.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1871/1871), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Unexpected end of command stream



/usr/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:124
        throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url +
                                                              ^
There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git
Please check https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#troubleshooting for potential explanations.
```

Comment: Just wondering what causes the lack of answers? Is my question not clear enough, or do you not know what causes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talked to the developer - it will not be fixed as Meteor 1.0 is coming anytime now and meteorite will be obsolete.